# show that $\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{1}{x-a}\left( \frac{1}{x-a}\int^{x}_{a}f(t)dt-f(a) \right)=\frac{1}{2}f'(a)$

Tags: calculus

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q: $f(x)$ differentiable-function in $\mathbb{R}$ show that 
$$\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{1}{x-a}\left( \frac{1}{x-a}\int^{x}_{a}f(t)dt-f(a) \right)=\frac{1}{2}f'(a)\quad (a\leq x)$$

Comment: Taylor expand $f(t)=f(a)+f'(a)(t-a)+o(t-a)$ and integrate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, Define $G(x) = \frac{1}{x-a}\int^{x}_{a}f(t)dt $, and G(a) = f(a)
to make make G continuous.

By the definiton of derivative,

G'(a) = $\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{G(x)-G(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{1}{x-a} \frac{\int^{x}_{a}f(t)dt-f(a)}{x-a} $ which is the left side of the equation.

Now since $G(x) = \frac{1}{x-a}\int^{x}_{a}f(t)dt $ is composed of differentiable functions on $(a,\infty)$,

$$\lim_{x\to a^+} G'(x) = G'(a)$$

Now we take G(x) and take derivative of it using Quotient rule, and we get

$$ G'(x) = \frac{(x-a)f(x) -\int^{x}_{a}f(t)dt}{(x-a)^2}$$

$$G'(a) = \lim_{x\to a^+} G'(x) = \lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{(x-a)f(x) -\int^{x}_{a}f(t)dt}{(x-a)^2}$$

$$ = \lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{(x-a)f'(x)}{2(x-a)}$$ (by L'Hospital Rule)

$$= \frac{f'(a)}{2}$$

Therefore $\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{1}{x-a}\left( \frac{1}{x-a}\int^{x}_{a}f(t)dt-f(a) \right)=\frac{1}{2}f'(a)$

Answer (score 3):

An easier way to do this is just to define $g(t)=f(t)-f(a)$. Then recognize that $$\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{1}{x-a}\left( \frac{1}{x-a}\int^{x}_{a}f(t)dt-f(a) \right) = \lim_{x \to a^{+}} \frac{\int_a^x g(t) \; dt}{(x-a)^2}$$ Then apply L'Hopital and the limit becomes $$\lim_{x \to a+} \frac{g(x)}{2(x-a)}  = \frac{1}{2} \lim_{x \to a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = \frac{1}{2}f'(a).$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the alternate definition of derivative.
Limit as x approaches a of (f(x)-f(a))/(x-a).

Sorry for the poor formatting; I'm on my mobile.